# JAVA add up string and return as string?

Tags: java, string

> Define a method named `x2y` that accepts a `String` and two `int`s as input, and `return`s (as a  `String`) the base `y` interpretation of the input `String`, assuming it is in base `x`.
>   Thus,  `x2y("1101", 2, 10)` must `return` "13", and `x2y("13",10,2)` must return "1101".

I need to write the above code using just charAt(int) and length() method. I am not sure how to start. All i have is:

```
package code;

public class Help {
    public String x2y(String s, int x, int y) {

        String answer = "";

        for (int i = 0; i<s.length(); i = i+1){

            char ch = s.charAt(i);

            return answer;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert any base to the decimal base:
The value of a digit is: (base^position)*(value of the digit).
Example: in base 16: 10 which is 16 base 10: (1) base 16 = (16^1)*1 = 16.

After that you got the value in decimal, do the following:

new digit = value % base, and output the new digit (if the base is above 10 you will need to use "which".

value = (value - new digit)/base

Until the value is less then the base.

We output the digits from right to left.

Comment: position starts from 0